# Can I check if QuickLook support/opens given file?

Tags: ios, quicklook

I am using Quick Look Framework for attachments preview and would need to mark unsupported files before launching the `QLPreviewController`. Can I programatically somehow check if QuickLook will actually preview the file and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [canPreviewItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/QLPreviewController/canPreviewItem:) property from QLPreviewController to check whether the item can be previewed by QLPreviewController

Btw these are the files supported by QLPreviewController([Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/QLPreviewController/canPreviewItem:))

> iWork documents
>
> Microsoft Office documents (Office ‘97 and newer)
>
> Rich Text Format (RTF) documents
>
> PDF files
>
> Images
>
> Text files whose uniform type identifier (UTI) conforms to the
>   public.text type (see Uniform Type Identifiers Reference)
>
> Comma-separated value (csv) files

Comment: Do you know how to check that on Mac?